# Flagging and answering?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Is it proper/accepted/correct etiquette to answer a question (for rep, bounty, etc.), but then flag it as a duplicate?

Or is this considered "gaming the system"?

Comment: I do it all the time.  But just be prepared to get your answer deleted. http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5536/44179

Comment: Please don't do it all the time.

Comment: The trick is to not do it all the time, only when it is really necessary...

Comment: I've made this a duplicate of the newer question [Is it okay to both answer and mark a question as duplicate?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17070) which was viewed, answered, and voted on by more people; explores the issue in more detail, as preventing auto-forwarding isn't the only consideration for answers on duplicates; and which I believe is more clearly asked and titled. Though I feel sure this closure is correct, gold tag badge powers do feel weird for meta--can one really be an expert on [meta-tag:discussion]?--so if you disagree, feel free to vote to reopen and/or request that I do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just not good tact. By answering the question you break auto-forwarding, which means we have to go and delete your answer to repair auto-forwarding when a user clicks on the question from a search result they go directly to the duplicated question.

tl;dr this is a borderline scumbag steve move.

[image: thanks bro]

Comment: So your saying it makes more work for you? (as mods)

Comment: It's bad community practice, not only does it make more work for moderators it makes it more inconvenient for users who are new to the site. You are all here as editors and maintainers of the site, the reputation really shouldn't be your primary goal

Comment: OK, I'll stop.  I just thought it made it easier on the OP to get an answer _then_ get it closed.  But I thought the answer deleting was automatic.

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering about that. Thanks for the answer (and the use of a meme!) :-D

Comment: @iSeth. Marking a question as a duplicate essentially *does* answer it (assuming the original has an answer; if not, answer the original).

Comment: @MarcoCeppi - answering questions isn't just for the rep - the point of a forum is to have a question answered, not just have flagged shut in 5 minutes... Rep ain't really worth much anyway, just a vague incentive, though it does show experience.