# What is the reason that I lost so much of the reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I am aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation) reputation system. However I would like to ask a compound statement. How much reputation will I loose if:

Someone asked a question which was then down-voted once, upon which I answered and someone up-voted my answer. After that a moderator deleted my answer and the question was closed being exact duplicate.
I guess in an all I should not loose reputation more that 10 because it was upvoted by someone and then deleted. However I lost 25 reputations in this event. I would like to know what I am missing upon?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230157/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-12-04-and-install-windows-7-back/230163) was the question which a fellow member asked. It is downvoted and closed being exact duplicate.! Following is my answer upvoted once and then deleted. [Screenshot of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPDbK.jpg)

I lost a reputation of 25 and I am unable to understand the individual events or if its a bug.[image: Screenshot of reputation]

Comment: If the question is not asked by me, so I think I should not be affected whether it's upvoted or downvoted or even closed by the community ?  Is it so ??

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5536/someone-deleted-my-answer-in-a-duplicate-post-why

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### history

The 25 reps was originally given when the OP accepted your answer and you gained an upvote.

i.e.

15 points for an answer, 10 points for an upvote = 25 rep.

However - the community considered that this question was a duplicate - it had already been answered by a previous question.  Being good citizens we closed the question with a link to the question.

#### why it was removed

That leaves the dangling answer.  Ask Ubuntu receives most of its internet traffic from search engines.  When someone is searching for a question, they click on a link and it lands on a Ask Ubuntu page.  Stack Exchange sites automatically redirects users to the correct web-page if the question has been closed as a duplicate - BUT only if the duplicate question has no answers.

Thus - being good janitors, your answer was removed - in this case by a moderator but it could equally been removed by high-rep community members.

The answer could have been merged with the duplicate question - however, the answer IMHO did not really substantially offer any new insights that were already covered by the duplicate, so was correctly deleted.

Deleting an answer, removes the unaccept status - thus 15 rep is removed.

For answers that have less than 3 upvotes, the system automatically removes those votes - thus the 10 rep removed.

#### conclusion

Its not a bug - just the way Stack Exchange sites work.  If you see a question as a duplicate, flag it as such.  Pop into chat to discuss with others if required.

It may seem harsh - but dont worry - its just one answer; we've all been there :)

Comment: Correct me if i am wronn, that the chronology was something like this... My answered was upvoted thus i got +10 , then the asker accepted it so +15... after that question being duplicate was closed hence my answer was removed loosing my 10+15=25 reputations... and my answer was not migrated to the orignal post since almost the similar answer already existed o'er there ??  :-)

Comment: @Z9iT - yep - that's what I said.  Pop into chat to discuss if you wish rather than through comments

Comment: Not a great issue, this is our community and i like'd that its beeng kept  clean by everyone of us.. i just wanted to know what hapened since i am new to the community and if i provided a right answer or it had scope to improve.. no hard feelings.. i am really sorry to say but i don't know how to pop into a chat , however a great thaks for your guidance.. you may now delete my comment once read :-)

Comment: @Z9iT - come and join us - its fun :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are aware of where the reputation came from, and you are aware on how you lost it. The reasons for it are explained here [Someone deleted my answer in a duplicate post, why?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5536/someone-deleted-my-answer-in-a-duplicate-post-why).

Lets put it this way, if the post is a duplicate an the contents of your answer are unique and useful, your answer would be merged with the main post and you would only loose the *accepted answer* reputation.

Since we are constantly cleaning up and your answer is similar with the ones already provided on the main post (note: not saying you copied it from there, its just redundant to have the same information on 2 similar answers on the same post) that did not happen. That only leave use with the option to delete your answer so that auto forwarding works.