# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

My answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/334939/can-ubuntu-run-alongside-windows was deleted - I'd like to know why.

As far as I can see none of the criteria mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers or in http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5536/someone-deleted-my-answer-in-a-duplicate-post-why were met.

I know that my answer doesn't target the title but it clearly (in my eyes) answers the last sentence of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answers that are posted on a duplicate questions break autoforwarding from search engines, so they're routinely deleted.

Comment: In that case it *might* be a good idea™ to put that reason at least into http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5536/someone-deleted-my-answer-in-a-duplicate-post-why.

Comment: @guntbert it's already said: *"will redirect users to the main post automatically if they land on the duplicate via a direct link, ie: search engines and similar, but that only is true if there are no answers present on the post."*

Comment: In support of Jorge's observation: this auto-delete function is a good thing. All too often people answer a question, whilst they know very well that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

The deletion of my answer was an automated consequence of the verdict *duplicate*. OK with me - the effort for this answer was not noteworthy anyway - and I certainly don't want to reopen the question!

What I want to **point out** though that those who voted to close the question as duplicate overlooked the last sentence (Very probably I would have missed it too :-)), which has no counterpart in the "original" question. That's why it doesn't make sense to move this answer to the other question - it would be an obvious non-answer there.

So I take this as a very unimportant example that we might delete correct and good information by applying overly quick close votes . Sometimes I find that I too answer/flag/vote mainly based on the **Title** of a question instead on the **whole question**.

As an aside: It might pay if people editing/reviewing questions tried to ascertain that the Title really matches the question.

Comment: In that case edit the question to make sense and then vote to reopen!